# VoiceOver does not read checkbox in a wizard in Eclipse

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, accessibility, voiceover

I have wizard and inside the wizard i have a checkbox and a text associated with the checkbox . While testing for accessibility i found that the VoiceOver does not read the text associated with the checkbox , it is read as "(un)checked checkbox". Have i missed something while adding the definition for the checkbox ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular here, how about adding the definition for your checkbox and the surrounding wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are SWT controls you can add an accessibility listener to set the text to be read:

```java
control.getAccessible().addAccessibleListener(new AccessibleAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void getName(final AccessibleEvent event)
    {
      event.result = "text for the control";
    }
  });
```

More on Eclipse Accessibility [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Accessibility)